# csv into multiple columns using split function using python

Tags: python

I am trying to split a specific column of csv into multiple column and then appending the split values at the end of each row.

I wanted to split second column on ',' and '.' and ';' and then append to each row respective values.

```js
import csv
fOpen1=open('Meta_D1.txt')

reader=csv.reader(fOpen1)
mylist=[elem[1].split(',') for elem in reader]
mylist1=[]

for elem in mylist:
    mylist1.append(elem)


#writing to a csv file
with open('out1.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    myf = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    myf.writerows(mylist1)
```

Can someone guide me further?

Comment: pls show the example of input and expected output. I can't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: are the values in elem[1] always the same length after splitting?

Comment: @RajatHanda I can't open the link and don't really want to download anything. So psl include couple lines of example in your question. That would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

To split with multiple delimiters, you can use `regex`:

```
import re
re.split(';|, |\. ', col_2)
```

Example from your file:

```
>>> col_2 = "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris;22"
>>> re.split(';|, |\. ', col_2)
['Braund', 'Mr', 'Owen Harris', '22']
```

Using this, try the following to achieve your desired output:

```
import csv
import re

with open('out1.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    with open('Meta_D1.txt', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            cols = re.split(';|, |\. ', line[1])
            del line[1]
            line.extend(cols)
            myf = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            myf.writerow(line)
```

Comment: You are right. But it is basically copying `mylist` to `mylist1`. So it is useless to have `mylist1`.

Comment: Thank You, @ettanany . This is what I need